# Select all the table cells, but not the embedded table's cells

Tags: css, selector

How do I select the cells in a table but not the cells of an embedded table?  There is a question on how to do this in [JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774774/how-to-select-table-cells-without-selecting-nested-table-cells-in-jquery).  I need to do this in CSS.

```
<table id="Outer">
    <tr>

        <td> --this one
        </td> 

        <td> --this one
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td> -- but not this one or any deeper nested cells
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

    </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use >, the child selector.
Example:

```
table#Outer > tbody > tr > td { color: red; }
```

The child selector selects only **direct descendents**.  More on the child selector: http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html.  But it's not supported by every web browser: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html.

Comment: no problem at all (and a +1, for providing a css solution, as asked for...as opposed to my jQuery-vision-provided solution...sigh) =)

Comment: Ha ha - we **all ** get excited when we find a question we can answer.  ;)

Comment: yeah, we *do*...but at 16k, I really *should* be past that first flush of excitement... XD

Answer (score 2):

As given by a comment in the linked question:

```
table#Outer > tbody > tr > td {  }
```

Note that because of cascading, changes will apply to the inner table as well unless you provide a default override style for all cells:

```
td { background-color: white; }
table#Outer > tbody > tr > td { background-color:red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95NAd/